# Increment In my Jquery No Working Fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment, hidden-field

i wanna increment hidden field value append in jquery but its not incrementing just printing "2" when i print value beforing initializing it to hidden field my code is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var k=0,j=0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
                var field = $("#field").val();
                 var DDL_fromProfession="<select name='ParametersFromProf' id='DDL_FromProYear'>";
                 for(var i=1950;i<2012;i++)
                 {
                 DDL_fromProfession +="<option text='"+i+"' value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
                 }
                 DDL_fromProfession +="</select>";
                var DDL_ToProfession="<select name='ParametersToProf'  id='DDL_ToProYear'>";
                for(var i=1950;i<2012;i++)
                 {
                 DDL_ToProfession +="<option text='"+i+"' value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
                 }
                 DDL_ToProfession +="</select>";
             k+=1;
                var newRow1="<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>from"
                +DDL_fromProfession +" to "+DDL_ToProfession +"</td></tr>"
                +"<tr><td align='center' style='font-size:large;color:#212121;' height'35px'>"
                +"<input type='checkbox' name='chkbx_CurrPro"+k+"' value='Yes'>I currently work here</input>"
                +"<input type='hidden' id='hide' name='hidden' value='"+k+"'></input>";
               // alert(document.getElementByName("valPro").value);
                //alert($('input').attr('hidden'));
                //alert($('input#hide').val());

                var input = "<input name='parameters' id='field' type='text' />";
                var input1="<input name='parametersCompany' id='field' type='text'/>"
                var newRow = "<tr><td align='center' style='font-size: x-large; color: #212121;' height='35px'>" 
                + input + " at " +input1 +"</td></tr>";
                $('#controls').append(newRow);
                $('#controls').append(newRow1);
                var value = parseInt($(":hidden[name='hidden']").val()) + 1;
                alert(value);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Hidden Field:

```
   +"<input type='hidden' id='hide' name='hidden' value='"+k+"'></input>";
```

Printing Value:

```
 var value = parseInt($(":hidden[name='hidden']").val()) + 1;
                alert(value);
```

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: There are too many useless code!

Comment: You use parseint, then do the alert, where do you keep the value of hidden plus one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the hidden value(`:hidden[name='hidden']`) = 2 (`value` writtent in `alert`)?

Then you must write a line after `var value = parseInt($(":hidden[name='hidden']").val()) + 1;` => `$(":hidden[name='hidden']").val(value);`

In this case your hidden value is `1` as you can test by `alert(parseInt($(":hidden[name='hidden']").val()))`